# Why is the Node Application not working on Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a basic Node App,

```
    const http=require('http');

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Service Started on port 3000')
```

with a Dockerfile having,

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean
EXPOSE 3000
ENV APP_PATH /usr/share/app
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
USER node
COPY . $APP_PATH
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I created an image of it using, `sudo docker build -t prototype .`
When I initialize a docker swarm using, `sudo docker swarm init`,I get this result,

```
Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on interface enp3s0 (2405:201:8008:881f:a137:a31d:cb90:b885 and 2405:201:8008:881f:1925:6903:a2e2:249) - specify one with --advertise-addr
```

Then running `sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr 2405:201:8008:881f:1925:6903:a2e2:249` and `sudo docker service create -d --name node01 -p 3000:3000 prototype` and then `sudo docker service ls`, I get the following result,

```
ID             NAME      MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE              PORTS
d7fu78estgkv   node01    replicated   1/1        prototype:latest   *:3000->3000/tcp
```

But when I open this url, `http://localhost:3000/` nothing comes, the browser keeps loading.

Comment: Does it work if you run it without swarm, i.e. just `docker run`?

Comment: Yes it does run